# Hotspot overlay with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a hotspot overlay with jquery right now there are 4 different hotspots to click on, the hotspots are located on a background image which is 100vh. as of now it functions, when i click one hotspot the content is shows, but when i click on the next hotspot the previous hotspot content is still shown. I need to write some kind of function that seperates each hotspot. All though I'm not sure where to begin.

Below is the html:

```
    <!-- overlay for hotspot on the background-image -->
    <div class="overlay-hotspot" id="hotspot-1">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <h3 class="white">
                Anna Meyer
            </h3>
            <h4 class="white">
                IT Spezialist, Frontend Teamplayer Lieblingsbuch: Sapiens
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-hotspot" id="hotspot-2">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <h3 class="white">
                Sabrina Schmit
            </h3>
            <h4 class="white">
                DevOps leiter, Frontend Teamplayer Lieblingsbuch: Sapiens
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-hotspot" id="hotspot-3">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <h3 class="white">
                Mathew Stokes
            </h3>
            <h4 class="white">
                Frontend Teamplayer Lieblingsfilm: 300
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-hotspot" id="hotspot-4">
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <h3 class="white">
                Franca Hoyer
            </h3>
            <h4 class="white">
                UX/UI Designer, Graphic professional..
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- end overlay for hotspot -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--hotspots-->
        <div class="hotspot" id="spot1">
            <div class="pulse"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hotspot d-none d-lg-block" id="spot2">
            <div class="pulse"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="hotspot d-none d-lg-block" id="spot3">
            <div class="pulse"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hotspot d-none d-sm-block" id="spot4">
            <div class="pulse"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- hotspots end -->


    // Hotspot functions //
// Hotspot 1 //

$('#spot1').on('click', function () {

  $('#hotspot-1').css("opacity", "1");

  return false

})

$('#people-hotspot').on('click', function () {

  $('.overlay-hotspot').css("opacity", "0");

  return false
});

// hotspot 1 end //

// hotspot 2 //
$('#spot2').on('click', function () {

  $('#hotspot-2').css("opacity", "1");

  return false

});

$('#people-hotspot').on('click', function () {

  $('.overlay-hotspot').css("opacity", "0");

  return false
});


// hotspot 3 start //
$('#spot3').on('click', function () {

  $('#hotspot-3').css("opacity", "1");

  return false

});

$('#people-hotspot').on('click', function () {

  $('.overlay-hotspot').css("opacity", "0");

  return false
});
//hotspot 3 end //

// hotspot 4 start //
$('#spot4').on('click', function () {

  $('#hotspot-4').css("opacity", "1");

  return false

});

$('#people-hotspot').on('click', function () {

  $('.overlay-hotspot').css("opacity", "0");

  return false
});
// hotspot 4 end //


$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function () {

  $('.dropdown-menu')
});
```

Comment: Have you tried making other hotspot's opacity to zero when you are clicking on any of the hotspots? Suppose, you are clicking on hotspot no 1 then make 2,3 & 4 to opacity 0. Like this.

Comment: It is a good idea but I am just not sure how to implement this inside of my Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('#spot1').on('click', function () {

    $('#hotspot-1').css("opacity", "1");
    $('#hotspot-2').css("opacity", "0");
    $('#hotspot-3').css("opacity", "0");
    $('#hotspot-4').css("opacity", "0");

    return false

})
    $('#spot2').on('click', function () {

    $('#hotspot-1').css("opacity", "0");
    $('#hotspot-2').css("opacity", "1");
    $('#hotspot-3').css("opacity", "0");
    $('#hotspot-4').css("opacity", "0");

    return false

})
```

Can you please try this one? Did you get it? Just do the same thing for spot 3 & 4 and change the opacity value accordingly.

Comment: You are welcome :) Happy to hear that :) Can you please give an upvote my answer and make it correct? That will be very helpful.